# Existence and Uniqueness of Bregman Projection

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am trying to work through a book which covers the Bregman Divergence. The authors adopt the following definitions:

> We call Legendre any function $F: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
> such that
>
> 1. $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and its interior point $\text{int}(\mathcal{A})$ is convex.
> 2. $F$ is strictly convex with continuous first partial derivatives throughout $\text{int}(\mathcal{A})$.
> 3. If $x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots \in \mathcal{A}$ is a sequence converging to a boundary point of $\mathcal{A}$ then $\|\nabla F(x_{n})\| \to
>    \infty$ as $n \to \infty$

> The Bregman Divergence induced by a Legendre function $F: \mathcal{A}
>  \to \mathbb{R}$ is a nonnegative function $D_{F}: \mathcal{A} \times
>   \text{int}(\mathcal{A}) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$ D_{F}(u, v) =  F(u) - F(v) - (u - v) \cdot \nabla F(v) $$

> The Bregman projection of $w \in \text{int}(\mathcal{A})$ onto
> $\mathcal{S}$ is $$ \text{argmin}_{u \in \mathcal{S} \cap
>  \mathcal{A}}D_{F}(u, w) $$

The authors then state the following result, saying that it relies on "standard calculus":

> For all Legendre function $F: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, for
> all closed convex sets $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$ such
> that $\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{S} \neq \emptyset$, and for all $w \in
>  \text{int}(\mathcal{A})$, the Bregman projection of $w$ onto
> $\mathcal{S}$ exists and is unique.

**How would I go about proving this?** I am aware that strictly convex functions on closed convex sets have unique minimizers, and that existence is guaranteed if the function has compact sublevel sets. But in this case $\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{S}$ may not be closed (nor convex?).

EDIT: For those curious, this is Lemma 11.1 from the book "Prediction Learning and Games", page 295.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this problem seems to be far from "standard calculus" and involves quite deep theory from convex analysis. I have found that this question in the literature is referred to as "zone consistency" of the Legendre function $F$. That is a function $F$ is zone-consistent if its Bregman projection is unique and always exists at every point. A proof that Legendre functions are zone consistent in reflexive Banach spaces can be found at the end of the following [paper](https://carmamaths.org/resources/jon/Preprints/Books/CUP/CUPold/MaterialII/ccm2.pdf) by Bauschke at al. Similarly, a proof for Euclidean spaces is listed as Theorem 3.12 in the following [paper](https://cmps-people.ok.ubc.ca/bauschke/Research/07.pdf) by Bauschke and Borwein.

Comment: A small correction: the proof for Euclidean spaces is in Theorem 3.12 (not 3.21). Thanks for the pointer I had the same doubt.

Comment: Thanks @Giovanni I will update the answer!